# express-ws communicate variables between front and back end

Tags: node.js, express, websocket, http-post-vars

I am writing a script that checks a devices gyroscope axis's with JavaScript. I need to send a front-end javascript variable, that is updated frequently, sometimes up to a couple times a second, to a back-end node.js variable. I heard that this is doable with `express-ws`, but if that is not necessary, that would be better.

If it matters, my JS variables are formatted similar to:

```
x = -103
y = 50
z = -10
```

(x, y, z could be a negative or positive integer)
Thanks!

Comment: _"couple of times a second"_ does suggest using some sort of permanent connection between client and server, so `WebSocket`'s seem like a logical choice.

Comment: @robertklep Ok, how can you send that over WebSockets? Seems pretty easy, or not?

Comment: Yes, it's pretty easy. Check out [`socket.io`](http://socket.io/) for a relatively simple framework.

Comment: @robertklep I have already looked over the chat example, and already have a working variable transmission, but all that code needs a POST request.

Comment: Which code needs a POST request?

Comment: @robertklep The chat example for socket.io (I think), and something I found on stack overflow

Comment: `socket.io` will automatically set up a web socket connection where web sockets are available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into `socket.send()` and `socket.emit()`.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10692110)

Comment: I am the author of the original post, but learned about those two @ndn